# How can I update a parameter in all data in the collection/ MongoDb/Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I need to set a specific value for a specific parameter in all data in the specific collection. For example; I have a database , my schema has age and name parameters and I want to update everyones age as 5. I've searched the questions but I couln't find any similar case. 
How can i do that or can i do that with mongoose or mongoclient or anything but mongoshell? I am using nodeJS mongoose and express.

Here is my code (Of course it's not working:)

```
'exports.changeAll = function (req, res) {
var reqparameter=req.body.parameter;
var database=req.params.database;
var collection=req.params.collection;
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1::27017/' + project, {
    useMongoClient: true,
})
    .then(() => { 
        var Project =  mongoose.model(collection, ProjectSchema, collection);

        Project.update({},{$set:{parameter:reqparameter},function(err,done){
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            else
                res.send('done' +reqparameter);
        }
        });
    });
```

}

//reqparameter= requested parameter value//

I've tried mongoclient too:(it's not working too,Error was about db.update is not a function)

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
console.log(collection,database);
db.update({}, { $inc: { parameter: reqparameter }},{multi:true});

console.log('done')
```

});

Thanks for your time and answers.

Comment: Your mongoose example did not use `"mutli": true` and your plain node driver sample does not actually use any collection object, and thus would error. Before you say something "does not work" you actually need to do the valid operation first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use **mongoose**, you should pass an *options* parameter to the update function and specify that you want to change all matching documents with `{ multi: true }`:

This should work:

```
Project.update({},{$set:{parameter:reqparameter}, { multi: true }, callback)
```